# What is the best practice to use kubernetes for local development?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am using docker containers and have docker-compose files for both local development and production environment. I want to try Google Cloud Platform for my new app and specifically Google Kubernetes Engine. My tools is Docker for Mac with Kubernetes on local machine.

It is super important for developers to be able to change code and to see changes live for local development.

Use cases:

1. Backend developer make changes to basic Flask API (or whatever you use) and should see changes on reloaded app immediately.
2. Frontend developer make changes to HTML layout and should see changes on web page immediately.

At the moment i am using docker-compose files to mount source code to local containers. But Kubernetes does not support relative paths to mount the source code.

Ideally i should be able to set the variable

> Deployment.spec.templates.spec.containers.volumes.hostPath

as relative path to my repo. For example, in our team developers clone repo to this folders:

> /User/BACKEND_developer/code/project_repo
>
> /User/FRONTEND_developer/code/project_repo

Obviously you can't commit and build the image after every little change to the source code.

So what is the best practice for local development with Kubernetes? Do i need some additional tools to modify .yaml files for every developer?

Comment: Have you checked [Skaffold](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/introducing-Skaffold-Easy-and-repeatable-Kubernetes-development.html)?

Comment: Helm allows you to specify value overrides that will be injected into the yaml. We have a “values.local.yaml” file that is gitignored and contains the hostpath for each developer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@tgogos is right.
The best way to achieve your goal is to use [Skaffold](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/introducing-Skaffold-Easy-and-repeatable-Kubernetes-development.html)

It will rebuild container whenever it sees changes in source code.

Skaffold has a pluggable architecture that allows you to choose the tools in developer workflow that work best for you:
[image: Pluggability]

Answer (score 1):

A very promising approach for dynamic languages is the hybrid approach recently introduced by [Skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold), allowing to take advantage of the usual auto-reload mechanisms. You can define two set of files:

- Changing a file on the first set triggers the full rebuild+push+deploy mechanism.
- Changing a file on the second set only syncs the file between the local machine and the container.

Such an hybrid approach is well suited to a large class of technology stacks, like Node.js, React, Angular, Python, where you can use the native hot-reload mechanism for source code changes, and trigger the full rebuild only when it’s needed (for example, adding a dependency). This helps a lot in keeping the latency low.

I spoke about this in my recent [talk](https://m.fornasa.it/talk/alldaydevops2018/) at All Day Devops. [Here](https://medium.com/@mfornasa/node-js-development-with-skaffold-file-sync-99c687b906d5) there’s an example based on Node.JS.

Comment: Martino, thanks for your answer. Can you please point me to the timecode in your talk when you speak about separate set of triggers for skaffold? Video is 4.3 hours long and life is short :) I am using Skaffold at the moment but i have to rebuild the image on every change. Dependencies is not a problem, they will not be installed every time if i put the requirements.txt(py)/package.json(JS) file at the first lines of a Dockerfile. But webpack bundling takes some precious time. It will be great to use React Hot Reload with Skaffold. Thanks.

Comment: @ZhorzhAlexandr video is 4 hours long but my talk is only 30 minutes :) Take a look at 1:20:52