# Kubernetes best way 4 locally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

Im new at kubernetes and would like to manage docker on my local servers.
Which ist he best way to use kubernetes locally?
Minikube just support 1 node. There are better ways?

Comment: Have a look at https://v1-13.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best practice to use kubernetes for local development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294165/what-is-the-best-practice-to-use-kubernetes-for-local-development)